# How to reverse arrows (tails) in Diagrammer, R?

Tags: r, diagrammer

Let's create a very simple diagram:

```
niv <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
from <- c("A","A","A","E","B","C","D")
to <-   c("B","C","D","B","C","A","E")
arr <- c(rep("normal",6), "inv")
temp <- data.table(from=factor(from, levels=niv), 
to=factor(to,levels=niv))
nodes <- create_node_df(n=length(niv), label=niv,
width=0.3) 
edges <- create_edge_df(from = temp$from,
to = temp$to, rel = "leading_to", label=temp$from,
arrowhead=arr, penwidth=3, color="blue")   
graph <- create_graph(nodes_df=nodes,edges_df=edges)
render_graph(graph)
```

[image]

The diagram shows edges from one node to another.
Usually people paint that edges with an arrow head, but I would like to paint some with the opposite symbol, a tail head.

I've found that by using the parameter **arrowhead="inv"** I can change the arrow to be a tail instead. (In my example the edge from D to E has a tail).

But there is a problem, the tail is painted on the wrong side.  I would like to paint it at the beginning of the edge (arrow).

How can I change it?

There is a parameter rel = "leading_to"  but I haven't been able to find what other values it can get.
Also there is a parameter "dir" but I don't know how to use it either.

Thanks.

A bonus question would be: How to prevent Diagrammer from writing the labels just above the edges?  I would like they don't overlap.

Comment: Does switching the "from" and "to vectors get you the result you want?

Comment: That was a possible solution I was thinking but I would need to switch only the edges I want reversed. Anyway I was looking for some more elegant solutions, without modifying the original input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch the dir to "back":

```
library(DiagrammeR)
library(data.table)
niv <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
from <- c("A","A","A","E","B","C","D")
to <-   c("B","C","D","B","C","A","E")
temp <- data.table(from=factor(from, levels=niv), 
                   to=factor(to,levels=niv))
nodes <- create_node_df(n=length(niv), label=niv,
                        width=0.3) 
edges <- create_edge_df(from = temp$from,
                        to = temp$to, dir = "back", label=temp$from,
                        arrowtail="inv", penwidth=3, color="blue")   
graph <- create_graph(nodes_df=nodes,edges_df=edges)
render_graph(graph)
```